# Piping ExpressJS(Response) And WebDAV(File)

Tags: node.js, express, webdav

Reading all contents of file into Buffer is just Useful for small files. bellow code reading entry file(all contents) as Buffer.

```
WebDavFS.getFile('/huge-file.zip',function(buffer){
   res.end(buffer); // use a lot memory and it is not optimized 
});
```

I need piping webdav file to response(expressjs) for large-files and many clients.

```
WebDAV.getStream('/huge-file.zip',function(webdav_stream)
   // this code is abstract
   webdav_stream.pipe(res); // use minimal memory 
});
```

Comment: You can create a readStream of the zip and pipe it to res. `fs.createReadStream('huge-file.zip').pipe(res)`

Comment: @SwarajGiri, I know , I want streaming with `webdav` protocol ( or reverse proxy with webdav and http )

Comment: If you are making a rest call, something like `request.get(url).pipe(res)` will work.

Comment: How to Use WebDAV as REST??